# Can I play WoW without buying the latest expansion?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I do not plan to buy the Warlords of Draenor expansion any soon.

Can I still enjoy playing the game up to Mists of Pandaria, if I would pay the subscription fee? I do own all the previous expansions. How to patch the game in that case? I played one year ago the last time.

Comment: Expansion*, Add-On is a term used for user-created additions to the game.

Answer (score 7):

Whether you enjoy it is up to you, but yes; it's perfectly possible to enjoy the game without owning all the expansions. Especially with a lot of old content revised, there should be plenty to do.

The game launcher will just patch the game for you automatically, including the latest expansion's data (afaik). Upon logging in, you'll be restricted to MoP content and level cap, though.

Low level content and new characters, there's definitely a lot to enjoy. However, at max level, I don't think there's a whole lot to enjoy. You may enjoy questing, exploration and limited achievement hunting, but in terms of PvE and PvP I think you'll find the community lacking - depending on your server, of course.

Comment: I can add that MoP comes with what is called the "core package" for free now that WoD is released. In other words, if you return to wow OR plan to start, you only need to buy core pack + Warlords of draenor.

Comment: `Whether you enjoy it is up to you` bloody brilliant.

Comment: You'll be considered a 90 twink at that point as well.  You still deal with changes that deal with your class/race.  Like Glyphs spells skills professions talents.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can still play the game, but you will not have access to Warlords of Draenor content:

- Your max level will be 90
- You will not be able to enter Draenor (the WoD one, not Outland)

  - No garrison
  - No access to Ashran world PvP
- You will not be able to play WoD raids or battlegrounds

You might find a guild of people who only play MoP content, but it's going to be a bit lonely on endgame. You can still do dailies, dungeons, raids, battlegrounds and arenas of all the prior expansions, though.

Comment: It's been a while since I've played WoW, but if I remember correctly, the Burning Crusade content for levels 60-70 was on Draenor.  What do characters of this level do these days?

Comment: @tjd That's correct, but now there are 2 "Draenor"s: Outland (from BC, levels 60-70) and the Alternate Timeline Draenor, which is called just Draenor ingame, home of the Iron Horde, untouched by Gul'Dan's portals and blahblahblah, for levels 90-100.

Comment: Gul'Dan didnt build the portal Medivh did.

Comment: @Virusboy Actually us both were wrong: I was referring to the various portals built that ultimately shattered Draenor into Outland, not the Dark Portal. Apparently Ner'Zhul built those: http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5058396073#5 These orc names are all too similar.